# Boolean 2d array text file

Tags: java

I need to read a series of # and blank spaces from a text file and print it as a maze.

```
public static void readMaze() throws FileNotFoundException{
  String fileName = "path/maze.txt";
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

  int x = 0;
  String columns = "";
  while (input.hasNextLine()){
    x++;
    columns = input.nextLine();
  }
  int col = columns.length();
  boolean maze[][] = new boolean[x][col];
}
```

So I have got the number of rows(x) and the number of columns which the maze will have.

Next step is to create a boolean array with a true value for each "#" and false for each blank space in the file and I am not sure how to do this.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()){
  columns = input.nextLine();
  for (int c = 0; c < columns.length();c++){

    if (c == '#'){
       add true;
    }
    else{
      add false;
    }
  }
}
```

So that is the next part, but I am not sure wht I need to put in the for loop, guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (c == '#'){` must be `if (columns.getCharAt(c)=='#'){` then you Need a Counter for rows and you have to the the values in the arry like maze[rowNumber][c] = true

Comment: u dont have to save true/false .. this will be redundant. Jens is right. And this might interest you: Guava Table https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Answer (score 0):

The only missing part of your puzzle is this

```
int row = 0;
while (input.hasNextLine()){
    columns = input.nextLine();
    for (int c = 0; c < columns.length();c++){
        c = columns.charAt(c); 
        if (c == '#'){
             result[row, c] = true;
        }
        else{
            result[row, c] = false; // not even needed, false is the default value ;)
        }
    row ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be better with something like :

```
ArrayList<Boolean> returnArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>()
for (int c = 0; c < columns.length();c++){

            if (columns[c].equals("#")){
                 returnArray.add(true);
            }
            else{
                returnArray.add(false);
            }
        }

return returnArray.hasArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        row = input.nextLine();
        String[] row_temp = row.split("(?!^)");
        int row_length = row_temp.length();
        for(int j=0; j<row_length; j++){

            if(row_temp[j].matches("#")){
                maze[i][j] = true;
            }
            else{
                maze[i][j] = false;
            }


        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please expand your answer with an explanation. Right now it's only code and not an answer.